# SpaceVim settings: line number and Python interpreter

Tags: linux, vim, python

In SpaceVim after install I have line number like that:

```
3
2
1
4 // this line
1
2
3
```

How I can chane it for normal view?

```
1
2
3
4 // this line
5
6
```

And when I put `Space l r` file runs in standart Python interpreter. How I can change it for ipython interpreter?

`Space l s i` open ipython but doesn't run file.

Comment: I found it for line number! Set `relativenumber = false` for disable in `~/SpaceVim.d/init.toml` in `[option]` section

Comment: You might want to check out the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for questions on Vim!

Comment: @filbranden Thanks. I checked, but don't found about Python :(

Comment: What I meant is that you should consider asking your questions there, since it's more likely you'll get Vim experts to help you there rather than here... Also, don't ask two separate questions. You should post your `ipython` question on its own. In my first read of your question, I missed it completely... Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For line number:

> Set `relativenumber = false` for `disable` in ~/SpaceVim.d/init.toml in `[option]` section